# Change button text on click with ember bindings, not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

**Component.js**
- I get here my button value and change it:

```
actions: {
    changeValue: function() {
        this.$().on('click', '.cellValue', function(event) {
            if ($(this).text() == '|') {
                $(this).text('-');
                $(this).val('-');
            } else if ($(this).text() == '-') {
                $(this).text('|');
                $(this).val('|');
            } else {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Template.hbs**
- There is a tables inside td buttons which text I want to change:

```
<table>
  {{#each-in rows as |table tableRow|}}
    {{#each tableRow as |singleRow|}}
    <tr class="as">
        {{#each singleRow as |tableRows|}}
        <td>
            <button id="button_id"{{action "changeValue"}} class="cellValue" value="{{tableRows}}">{{tableRows}}</button>
        </td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
   {{/each}}
 {{/each-in}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this Twiddle to show you how to update the value of your button.

https://ember-twiddle.com/3d192704ac6769c7bcc98c93ac9819f9?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  buttonText: 'oldValue',

  actions: {
    changeValue() {
      if (this.get('buttonText') === 'newValue') {
        this.set('buttonText', 'oldValue');
      } else {
        this.set('buttonText', 'newValue');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: how can I check value and after it set